# Code First Migrations: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having difficulty using Package Manager to run update-database.  Specifically, I'm getting a **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**

Approximately, the structure of my solution is as follows:

- Foo.Data
- Foo.Presentation

Foo.Data has all my EF code in.  Foo.Presentation is the presentation layer (in this instance, a MVC5 site)

With Foo.Presentation set as the startup project and Foo.Data set as the default project in Package Manager, whenever I try to run update-database I get:

**"Could not load file or assembly 'Foo.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."**

If I set Foo.Data as the startup project **and** the default project I can run update-database (so long as I specify the connection string and provider).

This has been driving me nuts all morning - so if anyone has any ideas, you'll help me get this sorted and preserve what remains of my sanity!

---

A couple of notes:

- I've recently branched the solution.  The old branch is working fine
- I've checked, double-checked and triple-checked that Foo.Presentation references Foo.Data.  It does, and I can access it from Foo.Presentation

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this same/similar problem - I was being an idiot.

The cause was a discrepancy in a couple of nuget package versions that were used in both Foo.Data and Foo.Presentation.  I had inadvertently used a newer version of the package in Foo.Presentation.